# Help Obtaining Numerical Approximation of Lambert W Solution

Tags: numerical-methods, special-functions, problem-solving, lambert-w

I am studying a particular generating function
$$\frac{2e^x}{e^{2x}+1+2x}$$
and I thought I would try to solve the equation
$$e^{2x}+1+2x=0$$ to determine for what value of $x$ if any the function would be undefined.  Because
$$e^{2x}=-1-2x  \Rightarrow e^{-(-2)x}=-2\left(x-\left(\frac{-1}{2}\right)\right)$$
Then the real solution is 
$$x=\frac{-1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}W\left(\frac{1}{e}\right)$$
As I have never used the lambert function I am trying to understand it.  I know that it satisfies 
$$x=W(x)e^{W(x)}$$.
How would I obtain a rough numerical approximation if I, say, didn't have a computer handy, or my cellphone to calculate?  How can one "see" a solution without the aid of technology?

Comment: I would try Newton's Method.

Comment: I was thinking that too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you search for Lambert function in Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), you could find interesting approximations for large values of the argument such as $$W(x)\approx L_1-L_2+\frac{L_2}{L_1}+\frac{L_2(L_2-2)}{2L_1^2}+\frac{L_2(2L_2^2-9L_2+6)}{6L_1^3}+\cdots$$ where $L_1=\log(x)$ and $L_2=\log(L_1)$ (this is for the pricipal branch).

Let us try for $x=1234$; the approximation gives $W(1234)\approx 5.42680$ while the exact solution should be $\approx 5.42669$.

For the general numerical solution, Newton and better Halley methods (as shown by Corless in the same page) are very efficient.

Comment: Well, I think this is a good start, but for the Newton or Halley methods to work, you need an initial guess.  While the asymptotic formula does give you a pretty good guess for large values of x, and there’s even a Taylor’s series expansion in the wiki page that works for small values of x (|x|<1/e), none of these even come close for... I suppose you’d call it a medium sized value?  Like, for example, 1 isn’t within that range, and it’s not a large number, so none of those formulas give you a good initial guess.